# How to only allow inbound traffic from the same IP address

Tags: network-security-groups

I'm trying to set up my Ec2 server on AWS, and I want to make it so only requests from the same ip address are allowed (for my backend port.). What security group allows this? The reason I want to restrict which ips can make requests to the backend is to stop abuse ips from making a ton of random requests.

Comment: you can make it from another security group also. But to allow a specific IP address you'd do the CIDR Block restriction - cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/32"] 32 is a specific IP. Make sure the IP wont change unless you don't mind updating it. If it's another instance or something that spins down and back up it'll change unless you use an elastic ip

Comment: You can select **All Traffic** and add your IP address as a source like **192.168.0.1/32** here **/32** represent only **192.168.0.1** IP is allowed for inbound traffic. [more info](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4632#section-3.1)